# how to detect incoming GSM call event in ios in the terminated/killed state?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I want to detect incoming normal call event in my app when my app is not in running(means killed/terminated state).

I want these things to do :

**1. detecting incoming call event**

**2. getting the caller mobile number who is calling**

**3. doing some stuff in the background. (like calling a web API)**

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't possible. You can't access the calling number for privacy reasons.

Comment: is there any way to find the first condition 1. detecting incoming call event

Comment: You can use `CXCallObserver` but it will only work while your app is in the foreground (ie, the active app)

Comment: is it possible to show a push notification on an incoming gcm call?